# UIView is retaining subviews after dealloc ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have a problem with one of my views retaining its subviews. The main view displays 'tables' in a restaurant, and loads a subview to display this 'table'.

When the main view is deallocated, the tables seem to remain allocated to memory. I have searched everywhere to try and find a solution to this as I just can't seem to fix it myself.

Firstly the code for the 'table' view:

```
@protocol tableDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)tablePress:(id)sender;
- (void)tableSelect:(id)sender;

@end

@interface tablevw : UIView
{
     CGPoint currentPoint;
}

-(void)changeOrderImage;
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame teststring:(NSString *)ts;

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *view;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *numberLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isEdit;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL hasOrder;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary * orderNumbers;
@property (nonatomic) int orderNumber;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *teststring;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *tableImage;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<tableDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

And the init method for the view:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame teststring:(NSString *)ts{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   if (self) {

        orderNumbers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

        isRemote = FALSE;
   NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tabletopRound" ofType:@"png"];

        UIImageView * iV  =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath]];

        self.tableImage= iV;


        tableImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 121, 121);

        locked = FALSE;

       [self addSubview:tableImage];


        UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTap)];

        doubleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;


        [self addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapGestureRecognizer];

    UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 50, 48, 20)];

        numberLabel = label;
        [numberLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [numberLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [numberLabel setText:ts];
        [self addSubview:numberLabel];


    UILabel * labelTwo  = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(24, 123, 70, 20)];
    nameLabel = labelTwo;
    [nameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [nameLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self addSubview:nameLabel];

    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

 self.tag = [ts intValue];

}


return self;
```

}

Finally, in the 'main' view the tables are added like so:

```
NSString *myString = [results stringForColumn:@"table_number"];

tablevw * tableView = [[tablevw alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x-60.5, y-60.5, 121, 121) teststring:myString];
tableView.delegate = self;
 [self.view addSubview: tableView];
```

The delegate is set to Nil when the main view is dealloced.  I have over ridden the dealloc method to log the dealloc calls to me - it is being called on the 'main' view but not on the 'table' view.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you try running the Analyzer on this application? Sometimes it can detect exactly what is being retained.

Answer (score 0):

In the dealloc method try

```
for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

It would be even better if u can try

```
[tablevw removeFromSuperview], tablevw = nil;
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry I forgot to say that I have already tried that with this : `[[self.view subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];`

Comment: Hi, I have added your method in to the dealloc method of the main view, although it is still retaining these views.

Comment: Hi, I have tried your edited code, however it wont let me try tablevw = nil; as I have to enumerate through the subviews to get these.

Comment: @larrysanchez don't enumarate. that's why i gave the second part of code separately. If you don't have the instance of tablevw accessible from dealloc method then at the time of adding give it some tag and get the instance of the table view using that tag.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your tablevw has a week reference to his delegate and that should be enough for to release the parent, but just for argue sake trie to nil tablevws delegate. Create an array of tablevw instances you created (or tag them as already suggested), then before you release parent remove them from superview, set their delegate to nil and kill the array. See what happenes, maybe that will help...